# go-flags ignore unknown input

Tags: go, flags

How do I make flags ignore unknown input and store it for further processing?
I've seen something about const IgnoreUnknown and I'm not sure how to use it because when I tried to put it as follows nothing changed:

```
    const (
       IgnoreUnknown = true
    )
```

Comment: The `flag` package does not have a direct way to ignore flags (and adding a constant value to your source is not going to change anything in another package). It would help to create a [mre] showing exactly what you are doing.

Comment: go-flags do.. I answered myself below.

Comment: If you’re referring to a 3rd party package in a question, it helps to give an unambiguous import path so we know exactly what package it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can strip unknown flags before passing them to `FlagSet.Parse()` manually.

```golang
func StripUnknownFlags(flagSet *flag.FlagSet, args []string) []string {
    formalFlagNames := getFormalFlagNames(flagSet)

    res := make([]string, 0, len(args))
    for i := 0; i < len(args); i++ {
        arg := args[i]
        isFlag, isTerminator, flagName, hasInlineValue := parseArg(arg)
        if isTerminator {
            res = append(res, args[i:]...)
            break
        }
        if !isFlag {
            res = append(res, arg)
            continue
        }
        isBoolFlag, exists := formalFlagNames[flagName]
        var appendTo *[]string
        if exists {
            appendTo = &res
        } else {
            appendTo = &stripped
        }

        *appendTo = append(*appendTo, arg)
        if !hasInlineValue && !isBoolFlag {
            // next arg is supposed to be the flag value
            if i+1 < len(args) {
                *appendTo = append(*appendTo, args[i+1])
            }
            i++ // skip the flag value
        }
    }
    return res
}

func parseArg(arg string) (isFlag bool, isTerminator bool, flagName string, hasInlineValue bool) {
    if len(arg) < 2 || arg[0] != '-' {
        return false, false, "", false
    }
    numMinuses := 1
    if arg[1] == '-' {
        numMinuses++
        if len(arg) == 2 { // "--" terminates the flags
            return false, true, "", false
        }
    }
    flagName = arg[numMinuses:]

    if equalsSignIndex := strings.Index(flagName, "="); equalsSignIndex == 0 {
        // std FlagSet.Parse() will return "bad flag syntax" error
        return false, false, "", false
    } else if equalsSignIndex > 0 {
        flagName = flagName[:equalsSignIndex]
        hasInlineValue = true
    }
    return true, false, flagName, hasInlineValue
}

// getFormalFlagNames returns a map where key is a flag name and value indicates it's a bool flag
func getFormalFlagNames(flagSet *flag.FlagSet) map[string]bool {
    flags := make(map[string]bool)
    flagSet.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
        isBoolFlag := false
        if boolFlag, ok := f.Value.(boolFlag); ok {
            isBoolFlag = boolFlag.IsBoolFlag()
        }
        flags[f.Name] = isBoolFlag
    })
    return flags
}
```

This code is from my [github.com/cardinalby/go-struct-flags](https://github.com/cardinalby/go-struct-flags/) flag-handling package that has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is very poor, so for future reference, it should be done as follows:

```golang
parser := flags.NewParser(&opt, flags.IgnoreUnknown)
args, _ := parser.Parse()
```

Comment: What package are you suggesting to use in this answer?